# Online(Realtime) recognition-Human action using CNN

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, feature-selection

I am a research student. I want to extract train a model for robot learning using some deep learning method. I have a set of videos, want to recognize human actions from videos. Where to start practically, never work before on video data.

Comment: You might want to ask this on [https://ai.stackexchange.com/](https://ai.stackexchange.com/), as your question is not so much about coding, but rather on ML methodology.
However, to get started, I'd explore sites like [papers with code (action-classification)](https://paperswithcode.com/task/action-classification) and see if any of those datasets is comparable to the data that you have and study the SOTA approaches listed there. Much success with the project!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.